# Consider using gRPC together with Message Queue such as RabbitMQ/Kafka in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, microservices, message-queue, grpc-java

I am currently do a project at university. I write the server in Java Spring Boot Application and I am now using gRPC to communicate between the server and the android application.

My project also have 2 more modules, which are in website, and window application.

My plan is to use gRPC to communicate with android and window application, REST for the website.
My supervisor at school recently advise me to consider using MQ together with current gRPC implemented on Server side.

Is it possible to use both gRPC and MQ ? and should I use those together ? 
Could you please explain for me? Thank you in advanced!